# Check if a string contains another string of numbers

Tags: python

So I apologize if this has been asked but I looked around and Ive seen input.split() for words and for single numbers in a string but I dont think they work for me. So I want to have a python script running in like a screen session waiting for an input and after someone enters `somethingsomething` and presses enter, the program looks for a string of numbers in the string that contains both numbers and special characters. And if it matches, something would run but if not, nothing would happen. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Cast your number to a string, and use the `in` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this . I hope this is what you are looking for

```
s="12342helloworls@#$"
n=raw_input('enter string')
if n in s:
    print "Found"
```

You can `in` statment to check for substring

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what I needed. Im pretty new to python as I usually use Visual Basics & java and it feels kind of different.